# onClick event in React app not working on iOS devices

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, svg, onclick

I’m having a bit of an issue with an onClick event (in the `Geography` component, which is a SVG) not working on iOS devices (seems to work fine when I’ve tested on other phones). I’ve done some reading and the consensus seemed to be this was a known bug, but by adding `cursor: ‘pointer’`  the issue should be resolved, however this hasn’t made a difference in my case so I think it must be a different issue. Any ideas?

```
import React, { memo, Component } from 'react';
import { ZoomableGroup, ComposableMap, Geographies, Geography } from "react-simple-maps";
import geoUrl from "../data/topo.json";
import Country from './Country'
import { CSSTransition, SwitchTransition } from "react-transition-group";

class Map extends Component { 

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            country: "",
            dish: "",
            description: "",
            photo: "",
            recipe: "",
            selected: false,
        }
    }

    handleEnter(country, dish, description, photo, recipe){
        this.setState({
            country: country,
            dish: dish,
            description: description,
            photo: photo,
            recipe: recipe
        })
    }

    render(){ 
    
        const { country, dish, description, photo, recipe, selected } = this.state;
        const countries = geoUrl.objects.ne_50m_admin_0_countries.geometries;

        return(
            <SwitchTransition>
                <CSSTransition
                    classNames="transition"
                    transitionAppearTimeout={50000}
                    timeout={500000}
                    key={ selected }
                    in={ selected }
                    unmountOnExit
                    appear
                >         
                    <> 
                        <section className="map" id="home">
                            <header className="header">
                                <button className="headButton" onClick={ this.handleAbout }><a className="subHeading" href="#about">About</a></button>
                                <h1 className="heading">Food Atlas</h1>
                                <button className="headButton" onClick={ this.handleList }><a className="subHeading" href="#list">List</a></button>
                            </header>
                            <div className="container">
                                <ComposableMap width={1200} style={{ width: "100%" }} data-tip="" projectionConfig={{ scale: 200 }} >
                                    <ZoomableGroup>
                                        <Geographies geography={geoUrl}>
                                            {({ geographies }) =>
                                                geographies.map(geo =>
                                                    <a href="#country" key={ geo.properties.NAME }>
                                                        <Geography 
                                                            key={geo.rsmKey} 
                                                            geography={geo}
                                                            onMouseOver={() => {
                                                                const { NAME } = geo.properties;
                                                                this.props.setTooltipContent(`${NAME}`);
                                                            }}
                                                            onMouseOut={() => {
                                                                this.props.setTooltipContent("");
                                                            }}
                                                            onClick={() => {
                                                                const { NAME, DISH, DESCRIPTION, PHOTO, RECIPE } = geo.properties;
                                                                this.handleEnter(NAME, DISH, DESCRIPTION, PHOTO, RECIPE);
                                                            }}
                                                            onTouchStart={() => {
                                                                const { NAME, DISH, DESCRIPTION, PHOTO, RECIPE } = geo.properties;
                                                                this.handleEnter(NAME, DISH, DESCRIPTION, PHOTO, RECIPE);
                                                            }}
                                                            fill="#44BBA4"
                                                            stroke="#E94F37"
                                                            strokeWidth="0.5"
                                                            style={{
                                                                default: {
                                                                    outline: 'none'
                                                                },
                                                                hover: {
                                                                    fill: "#E94F37",
                                                                    outline: 'none'
                                                                },
                                                                pressed: {
                                                                    outline: 'none'
                                                                },
                                                                cursor:'pointer'
                                                            }}
                                                        />
                                                    </a>
                                                )
                                            }
                                        </Geographies>
                                    </ZoomableGroup>
                                </ComposableMap>
                            </div>
                        </section>
                    </>
                </CSSTransition>
            </SwitchTransition>
        );
    }
}

export default memo(Map);
```

Comment: Have you tried to put onTouchStart only?

Comment: @dOshu I tried this but then it doesn't work on desktop

Comment: Hi, have you solved it? I got into this once I think. What I did was to have both onMouseEnd and onTouchEnd (use Start if you'd like). Check this [link](https://pastebin.com/ezZUiiNh).

preventDefault and stopPropagation will disable bubbling (if i'm correct), which means either one of the 2 events is triggered, the other will not be called. Hope this can help you.